# Can we change the color of Ambient Occulsion?

Tags: animation, materials, eevee-render-engine

I am working on a simple train scene. I turned on the Ambient Occlusion option. I was actually expecting black shadows near the edges (a default type) but instead, there were yellow shades. Is there a way to fix this issue or to change the Ambient Occlusion color manually ?? 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have recalculated normals properly.?

Comment: Yes, I did recalculate the normals for all the objects. I was getting this issue only when I was using a default HDR sky. It was back to normal when removed the sky and used background color. Anyway can you please tell me what did u mean when u said "recalculate normals properly" ?? Is it just by clicking "shift+ N" ??

Answer (score 1):

If I right understand you need a node AO.

Cycles:
[image]

Eevee:
[image]

You may see tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lB7l_IUcQn4

Comment: Thanks! It indeed helped me get proper details. But the main issue was when I was using the default HDR skies with "Bent Normals" turned on. Though the AO node helped in minimizing the white effect in the edges, there was still a bit of it.. So turning of the "bent normals" and changing to normal background world removed the white effect and give normal AO effect. Thanks for the video though!